# The parameterized query was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am still not accustomed to c# programming, specially in SQL. The error states:

> The parameterized query '(@ProdNo varchar(8000))DELETE FROM [ORDER] WHERE ProdNo = @ProdN' expects the parameter '@ProdNo', which was not supplied.

I don't know what to do. I need help. Thanks!

```
public void DeleteRecord()
{
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM [ORDER] WHERE ProdNo = @ProdNo", myCon);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ProdNo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;

            myCon.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            myCon.Close();
        }
```

Comment: The error talks about `@prodN`? or it is just a typo? However as above the query seems to be correct (apart from the counterintuitive fact that ProdNo = username)

Comment: That's it! It should've been ProdNo = ProdNo. Thank you sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since ProdNo appears to be character values and not a numeric, change your sql to, *sql quote* the value such as:

`DELETE FROM [ORDER] WHERE ProdNo = '@ProdNo'`

Comment: Thank you sir! It took me a lot of time to figure that out thanks to your help! Sorry for my beginners mistake :)

Comment: @YellowSubmarine It happens to all of us and the warning given is not that helpful. :-)